Why the MSO Outlook Desktop email client ignoring inline styling for color property?
Here's a piece of my code
<tr><td colspan="3" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 15px; padding-bottom: 17px;">[[STATUS]] - <span style="color: greenyellow !important;"> [[DELIVERED]] </span></td></tr>

even with the <p> instead of span, Outlook is not picking the color
I also tried with hex-code values, color names and using "<!--[if mso]>" but still same.
By the way I am using windows 10 and Outlook version - 2302.
